# MongoDB balance connections between nodes

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following scenario

MongoDB replica set named *myreplica*
3 nodes: *n1*, *n2* & *n3*

the 3 nodes have the same data.

I would like to connect to the 3 nodes and balance the reads from my site. Now I am using this connection string:

```
mongodb://myuser:mypassword@n1, n2, n3/?replicaSet=myreplica&slaveOk=true
```

That makes the two slave nodes to work with the reads, but not the primary.

How do I write my connection string in order to query any of the 3 nodes?

source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-modes

**UPDATE**

With `readPreference=nearest` option works. The three nodes lives in the same lan.

[image]

Comment: Well explained question. If I had seen it in this form I would have gone on to explain "tag-sets" originally. Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that would not affect your reads at all. All you are really doing is providing a **seed** list for your connection. And that is all you should be doing in a connect.

In order to decide what your want to do with interaction with reads, you need to set a [read preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) that is appropriate to what you wish to achieve.

In your case, what you *probably* want is to set this to [secondaryPreferred](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondaryPreferred) in order to allow reads from the *secondary* nodes as well as the primary. But obviously with that precedence.

Also please keep in mind that *replica sets* are not intended as a *scaling* option with MongoDB, but rather their purpose is for *redundancy* and *failover*.

If you want to distribute *performance*, then either *scale up* your hardware, or look into *scaling out* via implementing [Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/).

Comment: I am trying to use "nearest" option and looks like works (3 nodes are in the same lan).

Comment: @Jordi You can also look at [tag-sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/), which I did not mention in the answer to configure the rules that you want.